# How to follow xhtml to Bean class in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces, eclipse-juno

I'm using Eclipse-Juno & trying to follow `JSF` code from `xhtml` to `Bean class`, But i'm not able to get that feature in my work space.

**For Eg:**

when i'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+mouse pointer in header, it's giving suggested link.

[image]

But, when i come up with `xhtml` code i'm not able to get link to bean class.

**For Eg:**

Here i'm using same option, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+mouse pointer. It is not giving any suggestion to associated bean.

[image]

How to i get this? whether I have to change any settings in my eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear this kind of behavior in eclipse, we have to set configuration correctly. The answer given by **`Rami`** is partial to this problem.

When we download `Eclipse` for `JEE` the `Web Tools Platform plugin` will be download as inbuilt plugin. While running your `Application` / `Project` you have to configure for `Java Server Faces` in `Project Facets`.

The link to set configuration in Eclipse are,

`(Right click project) ->  Properties ->(Search for Facets) select Project Facets -> (Tick mark) Java Server Faces -> (click) Apply -> (click) ok`

For more detail See image below..

[image]

Now you can get link to `Associated Bean Class` form `xhtml` & You shall get default proposals also.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Web Tools Platform offers this

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.0.0/newandnoteworthy/jsf.php

> **Hyperlink support in WPE's Source tab**
>
> The Source tab of the Web Page Editor (WPE) supports Hyperlink on a
>   Managed Bean variable, Managed Bean property and Managed Bean method
>   referenced in the Expression Language(EL) of a tag-attribute. Users
>   can (Ctrl+click) on the hyperlink to navigate to the source of the
>   Managed Bean.

[image]

Comment: I will check with documentation, your answer not so clear with my requirement. what is `Eclipse Web Tools Platform` it's a plugin?? or what??

Comment: The problem here, My project inactive for `Java Server Faces configuration` i have clear it by going with `(Right click project) ->  Properties -> Project Facets -> (Tick mark) Java Server Faces -> (click) Apply -> (click) ok`. Now it works fine.!!

Comment: yes it is a plug-in, but if you download the JEE version of eclipse (which was your case), it will be already there. Have a nice time using it :)

Comment: Yeah, every thing okay.!! Look at my answer.!!